# Display category name and link in opencart 2.1.0.1 product page not work

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I need to display category name and link into product page in Opencart 2.1.0.1. I edit and add : **catalog/controller/product/product.php**

```
$data['text_linked_categories'] = $this->language->get('text_linked_categories');  
$query_linked_categories = $this->model_catalog_product->getCategories($product_id);
$linked_categories = array();
  foreach( $query_linked_categories as $linked_category_data ) {
       $linked_category = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($linked_category_data['category_id']);
       $linked_category_info['id'] = $linked_category_data['category_id'];
       $linked_category_info['href'] = $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $linked_category_data['category_id']);
       $linked_category_info['name'] = $linked_category['name'];
       $linked_categories[] = $linked_category_info;
   }
$data['linked_categories'] = $linked_categories;
$data['text_linked_categories']        = 'Categories:';
```

And for display: **catalog/view/theme/template/product/product.tpl**

```
<?php if( $linked_categories ){ ?>
    <li><?php echo $text_linked_categories; ?> 
        <?php foreach( $linked_categories as $linked_category ){ ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $linked_category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $linked_category['name']; ?></a>&nbsp;
        <?php } ?>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
```

See this error in errorlog:

> Undefined variable: linked_categories in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/oc/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_storage_modifi‌​cation_catalog_controller_product_product.php on line 269

Line 269 is: `$data['linked_categories'] = $linked_categories;`

I see blank and not show category and link. how do fix this?

Comment: I tried your code it's working. Is nothing displayed on the product page? OR Product image & description is displayed and only Categories you want to display are not displayed?

Comment: Are you refresh modification cache from admin after your changes? Please Go to admin > Extensions > Modifications and click on the blue Refresh button (top right corner) for update the system & then check it.

Comment: @saylibhagwat: U check in opencart 2.1.0.1 ?! Only categories name and link not show in my product page.

Comment: Yes I have checked in Opencart 2.1.0.1. Check whether any css is applied to anchor tag.

Comment: @saylibhagwat: see This error In Log: `Undefined variable: linked_categories in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/oc/vqmod/vqcache/vq2-system_storage_modification_catalog_controller_product_product.php on line 269` and css not problem

Comment: @saylibhagwat: Line 269 is: `$data['linked_categories'] = $linked_categories;`

Comment: post your catalog/controller/product/product.php file content

Comment: @saylibhagwat: http://pasted.co/1ce67e63

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have directly added line $data['linked_categories'] = $linked_categories;

```
<?php
class ControllerProductProduct extends Controller {
private $error = array();

public function index() {
    $this->load->language('product/product');

    $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->language->get('text_home'),
        'href' => $this->url->link('common/home')
    );

    $this->load->model('catalog/category');

    if (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
        $path = '';

        $parts = explode('_', (string)$this->request->get['path']);

        $category_id = (int)array_pop($parts);

        foreach ($parts as $path_id) {
            if (!$path) {
                $path = $path_id;
            } else {
                $path .= '_' . $path_id;
            }

            $category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($path_id);

            if ($category_info) {
                $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                    'text' => $category_info['name'],
                    'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $path)
                );
            }
        }

        // Set the last category breadcrumb
        $category_info = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($category_id);

        if ($category_info) {
            $url = '';

            if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
                $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
                $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
                $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
            }

            if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
                $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
            }

            $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                'text' => $category_info['name'],
                'href' => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . $url)
            );
        }
    }

    $this->load->model('catalog/manufacturer');

    if (isset($this->request->get['manufacturer_id'])) {
        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_brand'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('product/manufacturer')
        );

        $url = '';

        if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
            $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
            $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
        }

        $manufacturer_info = $this->model_catalog_manufacturer->getManufacturer($this->request->get['manufacturer_id']);

        if ($manufacturer_info) {
            $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
                'text' => $manufacturer_info['name'],
                'href' => $this->url->link('product/manufacturer/info', 'manufacturer_id=' . $this->request->get['manufacturer_id'] . $url)
            );
        }
    }

    if (isset($this->request->get['search']) || isset($this->request->get['tag'])) {
        $url = '';

        if (isset($this->request->get['search'])) {
            $url .= '&search=' . $this->request->get['search'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['tag'])) {
            $url .= '&tag=' . $this->request->get['tag'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['description'])) {
            $url .= '&description=' . $this->request->get['description'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['category_id'])) {
            $url .= '&category_id=' . $this->request->get['category_id'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['sub_category'])) {
            $url .= '&sub_category=' . $this->request->get['sub_category'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
            $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
            $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
        }

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_search'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('product/search', $url)
        );
    }

    if (isset($this->request->get['product_id'])) {
        $product_id = (int)$this->request->get['product_id'];
    } else {
        $product_id = 0;
    }

    $this->load->model('catalog/product');

    $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);

    if ($product_info) {
        $url = '';

        if (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
            $url .= '&path=' . $this->request->get['path'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['filter'])) {
            $url .= '&filter=' . $this->request->get['filter'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['manufacturer_id'])) {
            $url .= '&manufacturer_id=' . $this->request->get['manufacturer_id'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['search'])) {
            $url .= '&search=' . $this->request->get['search'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['tag'])) {
            $url .= '&tag=' . $this->request->get['tag'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['description'])) {
            $url .= '&description=' . $this->request->get['description'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['category_id'])) {
            $url .= '&category_id=' . $this->request->get['category_id'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['sub_category'])) {
            $url .= '&sub_category=' . $this->request->get['sub_category'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
            $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
            $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
        }

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $product_info['name'],
            'href' => $this->url->link('product/product', $url . '&product_id=' . $this->request->get['product_id'])
        );

        $this->document->setTitle($product_info['meta_title']);
        $this->document->setDescription($product_info['meta_description']);
        $this->document->setKeywords($product_info['meta_keyword']);
        $this->document->addLink($this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $this->request->get['product_id']), 'canonical');
        $this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/magnific/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js');
        $this->document->addStyle('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/magnific/magnific-popup.css');
        $this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/moment.js');
        $this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js');
        $this->document->addStyle('catalog/view/javascript/jquery/datetimepicker/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css');

        $data['heading_title'] = $product_info['name'];

        $data['text_select'] = $this->language->get('text_select');
        $data['text_manufacturer'] = $this->language->get('text_manufacturer');
        $data['text_linked_categories']        = 'Categories:';
        $data['text_model'] = $this->language->get('text_model');
        $data['text_reward'] = $this->language->get('text_reward');
        $data['text_points'] = $this->language->get('text_points');
        $data['text_stock'] = $this->language->get('text_stock');
        $data['text_discount'] = $this->language->get('text_discount');
        $data['text_tax'] = $this->language->get('text_tax');
        $data['text_option'] = $this->language->get('text_option');
        $data['text_minimum'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_minimum'), $product_info['minimum']);
        $data['text_write'] = $this->language->get('text_write');
        $data['text_login'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_login'), $this->url->link('account/login', '', 'SSL'), $this->url->link('account/register', '', 'SSL'));
        $data['text_note'] = $this->language->get('text_note');
        $data['text_tags'] = $this->language->get('text_tags');
        $data['text_related'] = $this->language->get('text_related');
        $data['text_payment_recurring'] = $this->language->get('text_payment_recurring');
        $data['text_loading'] = $this->language->get('text_loading');

        $data['entry_qty'] = $this->language->get('entry_qty');
        $data['entry_name'] = $this->language->get('entry_name');
        $data['entry_review'] = $this->language->get('entry_review');
        $data['entry_rating'] = $this->language->get('entry_rating');
        $data['entry_good'] = $this->language->get('entry_good');
        $data['entry_bad'] = $this->language->get('entry_bad');

        $data['button_cart'] = $this->language->get('button_cart');
        $data['button_wishlist'] = $this->language->get('button_wishlist');
        $data['button_compare'] = $this->language->get('button_compare');
        $data['button_upload'] = $this->language->get('button_upload');
        $data['button_continue'] = $this->language->get('button_continue');

        $this->load->model('catalog/review');

        $data['tab_description'] = $this->language->get('tab_description');
        $data['tab_attribute'] = $this->language->get('tab_attribute');
        $data['tab_review'] = sprintf($this->language->get('tab_review'), $product_info['reviews']);
        $data['product_id'] = (int)$this->request->get['product_id'];
        $data['manufacturer'] = $product_info['manufacturer'];
        $data['text_linked_categories'] = $this->language->get('text_linked_categories');  
        $query_linked_categories = $this->model_catalog_product->getCategories($product_id);
        $linked_categories = array();
          foreach( $query_linked_categories as $linked_category_data ) {
               $linked_category = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($linked_category_data['category_id']);
               $linked_category_info['id'] = $linked_category_data['category_id'];
               $linked_category_info['href'] = $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $linked_category_data['category_id']);
               $linked_category_info['name'] = $linked_category['name'];
               $linked_categories[] = $linked_category_info;
           }
        $data['linked_categories'] = $linked_categories;
        $data['text_linked_categories']        = 'Categories:';
        $data['manufacturers'] = $this->url->link('product/manufacturer/info', 'manufacturer_id=' . $product_info['manufacturer_id']);
        $data['model'] = $product_info['model'];
        $data['reward'] = $product_info['reward'];
        $data['points'] = $product_info['points'];
        $data['description'] = html_entity_decode($product_info['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

        if ($product_info['quantity'] <= 0) {
            $data['stock'] = $product_info['stock_status'];
        } elseif ($this->config->get('config_stock_display')) {
            $data['stock'] = $product_info['quantity'];
        } else {
            $data['stock'] = $this->language->get('text_instock');
        }

        $this->load->model('tool/image');

        $manufacturer_image = $this->model_catalog_manufacturer->getManufacturer($product_info['manufacturer_id']);
            if($manufacturer_image){
                $data['manufacturers_img'] = $this->model_tool_image->thumbs($manufacturer_image['image'], 30, 30);
            } else  {
            $data['manufacturers_img'] = false;
        }


        if ($product_info['image']) {
            $data['popup'] = $this->model_tool_image->thumbs($product_info['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_popup_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_popup_height'));
        } else {
            $data['popup'] = '';
        }

        if ($product_info['image']) {
            $data['thumb'] = $this->model_tool_image->thumbs($product_info['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_thumb_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_thumb_height'));
        } else {
            $data['thumb'] = '';
        }

        $data['images'] = array();

        $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductImages($this->request->get['product_id']);

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            $data['images'][] = array(
                'popup' => $this->model_tool_image->thumbs($result['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_popup_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_popup_height')),
                'thumb' => $this->model_tool_image->thumbs($result['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_additional_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_additional_height'))
            );
        }

        if (($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
            $data['price'] = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_info['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
        } else {
            $data['price'] = false;
        }

        if ((float)$product_info['special']) {
            $data['special'] = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_info['special'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
        } else {
            $data['special'] = false;
        }

        if ($this->config->get('config_tax')) {
            $data['tax'] = $this->currency->format((float)$product_info['special'] ? $product_info['special'] : $product_info['price']);
        } else {
            $data['tax'] = false;
        }

        $discounts = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductDiscounts($this->request->get['product_id']);

        $data['discounts'] = array();

        foreach ($discounts as $discount) {
            $data['discounts'][] = array(
                'quantity' => $discount['quantity'],
                'price'    => $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($discount['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')))
            );
        }

        $data['options'] = array();

        foreach ($this->model_catalog_product->getProductOptions($this->request->get['product_id']) as $option) {
            $product_option_value_data = array();

            foreach ($option['product_option_value'] as $option_value) {
                if (!$option_value['subtract'] || ($option_value['quantity'] > 0)) {
                    if ((($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) && (float)$option_value['price']) {
                        $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($option_value['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax') ? 'P' : false));
                    } else {
                        $price = false;
                    }

                    $product_option_value_data[] = array(
                        'product_option_value_id' => $option_value['product_option_value_id'],
                        'option_value_id'         => $option_value['option_value_id'],
                        'name'                    => $option_value['name'],
                        'image'                   => $this->model_tool_image->thumbs($option_value['image'], 50, 50),
                        'price'                   => $price,
                        'price_prefix'            => $option_value['price_prefix']
                    );
                }
            }

            $data['options'][] = array(
                'product_option_id'    => $option['product_option_id'],
                'product_option_value' => $product_option_value_data,
                'option_id'            => $option['option_id'],
                'name'                 => $option['name'],
                'type'                 => $option['type'],
                'value'                => $option['value'],
                'required'             => $option['required']
            );
        }

        if ($product_info['minimum']) {
            $data['minimum'] = $product_info['minimum'];
        } else {
            $data['minimum'] = 1;
        }

        $data['review_status'] = $this->config->get('config_review_status');

        if ($this->config->get('config_review_guest') || $this->customer->isLogged()) {
            $data['review_guest'] = true;
        } else {
            $data['review_guest'] = false;
        }

        if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
            $data['customer_name'] = $this->customer->getFirstName() . '&nbsp;' . $this->customer->getLastName();
        } else {
            $data['customer_name'] = '';
        }

        $data['reviews'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_reviews'), (int)$product_info['reviews']);
        $data['rating'] = (int)$product_info['rating'];

        // Captcha
        if ($this->config->get($this->config->get('config_captcha') . '_status') && in_array('review', (array)$this->config->get('config_captcha_page'))) {
            $data['captcha'] = $this->load->controller('captcha/' . $this->config->get('config_captcha'));
        } else {
            $data['captcha'] = '';
        }

        $data['attribute_groups'] = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductAttributes($this->request->get['product_id']);

        $data['products'] = array();

        $results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProductRelated($this->request->get['product_id']);

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            if ($result['image']) {
                $image = $this->model_tool_image->thumbs($result['image'], $this->config->get('config_image_related_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_related_height'));
            } else {
                $image = $this->model_tool_image->thumbs('placeholder.png', $this->config->get('config_image_related_width'), $this->config->get('config_image_related_height'));
            }

            if (($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
                $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['price'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
            } else {
                $price = false;
            }

            if ((float)$result['special']) {
                $special = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($result['special'], $result['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
            } else {
                $special = false;
            }

            if ($this->config->get('config_tax')) {
                $tax = $this->currency->format((float)$result['special'] ? $result['special'] : $result['price']);
            } else {
                $tax = false;
            }

            if ($this->config->get('config_review_status')) {
                $rating = (int)$result['rating'];
            } else {
                $rating = false;
            }

            $data['products'][] = array(
                'product_id'  => $result['product_id'],
                'thumb'       => $image,
                'name'        => $result['name'],
                'description' => utf8_substr(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')), 0, $this->config->get('config_product_description_length')) . '..',
                'price'       => $price,
                'special'     => $special,
                'tax'         => $tax,
                'minimum'     => $result['minimum'] > 0 ? $result['minimum'] : 1,
                'rating'      => $rating,
                'href'        => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $result['product_id'])
            );
        }

        $data['tags'] = array();

        if ($product_info['tag']) {
            $tags = explode(',', $product_info['tag']);

            foreach ($tags as $tag) {
                $data['tags'][] = array(
                    'tag'  => trim($tag),
                    'href' => $this->url->link('product/search', 'tag=' . trim($tag))
                );
            }
        }

        $data['recurrings'] = $this->model_catalog_product->getProfiles($this->request->get['product_id']);

        $this->model_catalog_product->updateViewed($this->request->get['product_id']);

        $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
        $data['column_right'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_right');
        $data['content_top'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_top');
        $data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_bottom');
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
        $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');

        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/product.tpl')) {
            $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/product.tpl', $data));
        } else {
            $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('default/template/product/product.tpl', $data));
        }
    } else {
        $url = '';

        if (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
            $url .= '&path=' . $this->request->get['path'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['filter'])) {
            $url .= '&filter=' . $this->request->get['filter'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['manufacturer_id'])) {
            $url .= '&manufacturer_id=' . $this->request->get['manufacturer_id'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['search'])) {
            $url .= '&search=' . $this->request->get['search'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['tag'])) {
            $url .= '&tag=' . $this->request->get['tag'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['description'])) {
            $url .= '&description=' . $this->request->get['description'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['category_id'])) {
            $url .= '&category_id=' . $this->request->get['category_id'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['sub_category'])) {
            $url .= '&sub_category=' . $this->request->get['sub_category'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
            $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
            $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
        }

        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text' => $this->language->get('text_error'),
            'href' => $this->url->link('product/product', $url . '&product_id=' . $product_id)
        );

        $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('text_error'));

        $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('text_error');

        $data['text_error'] = $this->language->get('text_error');

        $data['button_continue'] = $this->language->get('button_continue');

        $data['continue'] = $this->url->link('common/home');

        $this->response->addHeader($this->request->server['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 404 Not Found');

        $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
        $data['column_right'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_right');
        $data['content_top'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_top');
        $data['content_bottom'] = $this->load->controller('common/content_bottom');
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');
        $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');

        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/error/not_found.tpl')) {
            $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/error/not_found.tpl', $data));
        } else {
            $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('default/template/error/not_found.tpl', $data));
        }
    }
}

public function review() {
    $this->load->language('product/product');

    $this->load->model('catalog/review');

    $data['text_no_reviews'] = $this->language->get('text_no_reviews');

    if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
        $page = $this->request->get['page'];
    } else {
        $page = 1;
    }

    $data['reviews'] = array();

    $review_total = $this->model_catalog_review->getTotalReviewsByProductId($this->request->get['product_id']);

    $results = $this->model_catalog_review->getReviewsByProductId($this->request->get['product_id'], ($page - 1) * 5, 5);

    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $data['reviews'][] = array(
            'author'     => $result['author'],
            'text'       => nl2br($result['text']),
            'rating'     => (int)$result['rating'],
            'date_added' => ($this->language->get('code') == 'fa') ? jdate($this->config->get('config_shamsidate_format'), strtotime($result['date_added'])) : ($this->language->get('code') == 'fa') ? jdate($this->config->get('config_shamsidate_format'), strtotime($result['date_added'])) : date($this->language->get('date_format_short'), strtotime($result['date_added']))
        );
    }

    $pagination = new Pagination();
    $pagination->total = $review_total;
    $pagination->page = $page;
    $pagination->limit = 5;
    $pagination->url = $this->url->link('product/product/review', 'product_id=' . $this->request->get['product_id'] . '&page={page}');

    $data['pagination'] = $pagination->render();

    $data['results'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_pagination'), ($review_total) ? (($page - 1) * 5) + 1 : 0, ((($page - 1) * 5) > ($review_total - 5)) ? $review_total : ((($page - 1) * 5) + 5), $review_total, ceil($review_total / 5));

    if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/review.tpl')) {
        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/product/review.tpl', $data));
    } else {
        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('default/template/product/review.tpl', $data));
    }
}

public function write() {
    $this->load->language('product/product');

    $json = array();

    if ($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['name']) < 3) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['name']) > 25)) {
            $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_name');
        }

        if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['text']) < 25) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['text']) > 1000)) {
            $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_text');
        }

        if (empty($this->request->post['rating']) || $this->request->post['rating'] < 0 || $this->request->post['rating'] > 5) {
            $json['error'] = $this->language->get('error_rating');
        }

        // Captcha
        if ($this->config->get($this->config->get('config_captcha') . '_status') && in_array('review', (array)$this->config->get('config_captcha_page'))) {
            $captcha = $this->load->controller('captcha/' . $this->config->get('config_captcha') . '/validate');

            if ($captcha) {
                $json['error'] = $captcha;
            }
        }

        if (!isset($json['error'])) {
            $this->load->model('catalog/review');

            $this->model_catalog_review->addReview($this->request->get['product_id'], $this->request->post);

            $json['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');
        }
    }

    $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
    $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
}

public function getRecurringDescription() {
    $this->language->load('product/product');
    $this->load->model('catalog/product');

    if (isset($this->request->post['product_id'])) {
        $product_id = $this->request->post['product_id'];
    } else {
        $product_id = 0;
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['recurring_id'])) {
        $recurring_id = $this->request->post['recurring_id'];
    } else {
        $recurring_id = 0;
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['quantity'])) {
        $quantity = $this->request->post['quantity'];
    } else {
        $quantity = 1;
    }

    $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product_id);
            $data['text_linked_categories'] = $this->language->get('text_linked_categories');

            $query_linked_categories = $this->model_catalog_product->getCategories($product_id);
            $linked_categories = array();
            foreach( $query_linked_categories as $linked_category_data ) {
                $linked_category = $this->model_catalog_category->getCategory($linked_category_data['category_id']);
                $linked_category_info['id'] = $linked_category_data['category_id'];
                $linked_category_info['href'] = $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $linked_category_data['category_id']);
                $linked_category_info['name'] = $linked_category['name'];
                $linked_categories[] = $linked_category_info;
            }
    $recurring_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProfile($product_id, $recurring_id);

    $json = array();

    if ($product_info && $recurring_info) {
        if (!$json) {
            $frequencies = array(
                'day'        => $this->language->get('text_day'),
                'week'       => $this->language->get('text_week'),
                'semi_month' => $this->language->get('text_semi_month'),
                'month'      => $this->language->get('text_month'),
                'year'       => $this->language->get('text_year'),
            );

            if ($recurring_info['trial_status'] == 1) {
                $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($recurring_info['trial_price'] * $quantity, $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
                $trial_text = sprintf($this->language->get('text_trial_description'), $price, $recurring_info['trial_cycle'], $frequencies[$recurring_info['trial_frequency']], $recurring_info['trial_duration']) . ' ';
            } else {
                $trial_text = '';
            }

            $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($recurring_info['price'] * $quantity, $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));

            if ($recurring_info['duration']) {
                $text = $trial_text . sprintf($this->language->get('text_payment_description'), $price, $recurring_info['cycle'], $frequencies[$recurring_info['frequency']], $recurring_info['duration']);
            } else {
                $text = $trial_text . sprintf($this->language->get('text_payment_cancel'), $price, $recurring_info['cycle'], $frequencies[$recurring_info['frequency']], $recurring_info['duration']);
            }

            $json['success'] = $text;
        }
    }

    $this->response->addHeader('Content-Type: application/json');
    $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
}
```

}

Comment: If remove line 269 error fix So category name not show and not work. can u share worked code?

Comment: not display and see error: `PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: linked_categories in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/oc/catalog/view/theme/storie/template/product/product.tpl on line 266`